# Continue the number sequence: 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 15, 20,

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

I can see that the length of each missing subsequence is greater by one than the length of the previous one.
But I can't figure out how to determine its start number.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking?

Comment: I'm asking for the continuation of the sequence, i.e. the next element of it

Comment: Do you know the answer? What if the sequence is incorrect?

Comment: No, I don't know the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next values would be

> 21, 22, 28, 29, 30....

The reason for this

> the pattern that repeats is *i+pn, i+pn, 1+pn, 1+pn, i+pn, 1+pn, 1+pn* repeat 
>  where *pn = previous number in the sequence* 
>  i's value in the sequence constantly increases by 1 so the next sequence would be 
>  *4+pn, 5+pn, 1+pn, 1+pn, 6+pn, 1+pn, 1+pn* 
>  15, 20, 21, 22, 28, 29, 30

Comment: Is there enough information in this sequence to justify this pattern?

Comment: @Emrakul I edited to show that the pattern continued from the numbers in the question. It was my best shot at trying to explain the sequence.